# Find entities which has fewer than n sub-entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to find an easy way to pick out a single customer service representative to assign to a given user. I have the following models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // SNIP
    public virtual Representative Representative { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class Representative
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MaxActiveCustomers { get; set; }
    // all the customers this representative has interacted with
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to find any representatives who currently has fewer `Customers` than `MaxActiveCustomers` suggests.

My attempt:

```
from r in Representatives
where r.MaxActiveCustomers > r.Customers.Count(c => c.Active)
select r
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'Customers' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Besides I think Count(predicate) will not work in Linq to entities. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)(search for count)

Comment: @Reniuz Count should work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined `Customers` as of type `IEnumerable<Customer>`, which EF does not consider as part of the model. Change the type to  `ICollection<Customer>`.

Comment: I knew it had to be something really simple. That's what I get for posting to SO before having my code reviewed by someone else... :)